# Protect Cisco C3560CX switch from unauthorized access on remote location

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios, security

I have to extend our corporate lan to remote location on which we can not control the physical access to the switch.

What are the best practices in this case/scenario? So, I will shut down password recovery. I will shutdown all unused ports. Maybe disable console access? What about usb port?

Comment: I wouldn't shut the management or console ports off completely, in case something goes wrong and you need someone local to the switch to assist with getting it back online again, and may need those ports to view logs to figure out what's going on. I'd just lock down access to specific remote host IPs and use SSH (instead of Telnet), and set up AAA to apply to the console interfaces so they're restricted. The rest is fine as long as you keep track of the password and never need the password recovery feature.  The USB port shares the Console port's AAA config.

Comment: Ok, when you said: "set up AAA to apply to the console interfaces so they're restricted. The USB port shares the Console port's AAA config"...can you post some commands for this? Because I do not have AAA server on this network can I configure the switch for local authentication and authorization?

Comment: If you search, Cisco has documents regarding the hardening of its network devices. In fact, I do not think you can disable the console interface, but you can certainly configure some protection.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Best practice: buy a lockable wall mount rack  cabinet and put the switch in it.

Comment: Ok, I respect your professional opinion but can you be more specific what are the possibilities to compromise the switch in that environment? What is his weak spot?

Comment: Weakness: saws, crowbars and sledgehammers

Comment: Ok, then I will buy armored, bulletproof wall mount rack. Thanks for advice.

Comment: If you’re that concerned be sure that your security team installs a video camera to watch the rack area

Comment: If you use a lockable cabinet, you should also include some kind of tamper alarm to alert you when Mike comes with his sledgehammer.